# Running Azure functions with IoT Hub trigger

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am trying to run an azure function locally in Visual Studio 2017 preview with latest tooling for azure functions. i want to know how to pull function.json as my function works on the azure portal but not locally in VS2017.

Looking forward on how to set iot hub connection endpoint settings in local.settings.json file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VS2017 tooling `function.json` file isn't created manually anymore. Instead, it's being generated at publish time from attributes that you put on your function parameters. In your case you will use `EventHubTrigger` attribute, see several examples in [wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support).

Having  an existing `function.json`, you should copy each property-value pair from the binding to the corresponding property of `EventHubTrigger` attribute. There's not automated way to do that.

`local.settings.json` is the container to put your app settings while running function locally from VS. They are just key-value pairs, go copy your settings from the portal if you have them there already. This file has no effect on deployment to Azure.